# How to plot multiple variables on the same plot in ggplot in geom_line after melting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt

I have a tibble where the column names of original df were given by values in variable col that i melted into long format using `id.vars=Country` to get this using `melt`. This is to plot the different values of *AGR_LogLabProd, MIN_LogLabProd, MAN_LogLabProd* by year on the same x-axis .

**CHN4**

```
Country  Year  variable  value
---------------------------

1      CHN 1958 AGR_LogLabProd 14.81782  
2      CHN 1959 AGR_LogLabProd 14.61870  
3      CHN 1960 AGR_LogLabProd 14.41969  
4      CHN 1961 AGR_LogLabProd 14.28257  
5      CHN 1958 MIN_LogLabProd 13.67850  
6      CHN 1959 MIN_LogLabProd 14.24685  
7      CHN 1960 MIN_LogLabProd 14.57734  
8      CHN 1961 MIN_LogLabProd 14.59046  
9      CHN 1958 MAN_LogLabProd 13.29359  
10     CHN 1959 MAN_LogLabProd 13.86194  
11     CHN 1960 MAN_LogLabProd 14.19243  
12     CHN 1961 MAN_LogLabProd 14.20556
```

I use `ggplot(CHN4, aes(x=Year, y=value))+geom_line()`but its giving me a strange plot (given in the attached image) [image],  not seperate lines for each variable in the variable column as expected . Any clue to whats going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem. You need to include a grouping variable. If you want to use color for every different level, you would use

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(CHN4, aes(x=Year, y=value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

but if you don't care for colors, you can do

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(CHN4, aes(x=Year, y=value, group = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: That sorts it out. Thanks a ton !